# Selenium WebDriver with RadWindow

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, radwindow

I am attempting to access a form within a RadWindow. The web page uses `window.radopen()` to generate an ASP.NET popup. I need to access that popup, edit it, and click a button. Is there a way to do this using Selenium WebDriver?

Specifically, the radwindow contains a textarea with an id of "txtEntries" and a button with and id of "btnAccept". I have tried finding the textarea first, as below, with no luck.

I am currently attempting:

```
state = wait.Until<IWebElement>((d) =>
            {
                return d.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div#radWindow #txtEntries"));
            });
```

With failed results.

Comment: From my nightmare time using Rad controls, I believe it uses an iframe? Could you dive into the HTML source and check?

Comment: .NET stuff isn't my thing.  Take this from me @Arran ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yea, there's a way.. Since RadWindow is not an actual window, it makes it significantly easier.

First, use CSS and have a parent selector. Something like,

```
div#radWindow
```

Then just add the elements you want to find to that. e.g.

```
input[type='text'].someclass
```

then just concatenate them, so it turns into this -

```
div#radWindow input[type='text'].someclass
```

which translates in CSS to "first find a div with id radWindow, and find an input that is a descendant of the div, with the `type` attribute that equals `text` that has `someclass` attached.

Comment: How does this translate into using Selenium WebDriver? I've been using driver.FindElement(By.ID("ID")); typically. What would the find code look like?

Comment: It would look something like, `FindElement(By.cssSelector("div#radWindow input[type='submit']"))`

Comment: I've tried your code and edited my OP to include my attempt, but it still cannot find the element. Any thoughts?

Comment: i am ignorant of RadWindow's.   Inspect the parent element that the RadWindow uses and use that.  #radWindow was just my guess.. you'll have to figure out what it is

Comment: Ah, well I can't see any of the code for the rad window when it loads in. I know it loads using a seperate page, ajax-like, and can see that code, but not how it fits when loaded from the main page itself. I don't know much about rad windows.